# How do I type a string containing less than 5 characters and still continue to the next row of code?

Tags: string, ada

```
with Ada.Text_IO;              use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;        use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

procedure Help is
    F: Float
    S: String(1..6);
begin
    Put("Type a string with max 5 characters: ");
    Get_Line(S(1..5), I);
    Put("You typed the string: ");
    Put(S(1..I));
    Skip_Line;
    New_Line;

    Put("Type a string with max 5 characters: ");
    Get_Line(S(1..5), I);
    Put("You typed the string: ");
    Put(S(1..I));
end Help;
```

[When I run this code, and for instance type "Hey brother" I get "Hey b" as an output, and then it continues to the next problem. All good and clear!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wzfE.png)

[But when I type a string containing less than 5 characters like "Hey", it types it out like expected BUT it is still waiting for me to fill out the string containing 5 characters. It's supposed to jump to the next problem but it doesn't. If I now type "ss", you will get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2nVh.png)

["Heyss" and then it continues to the next problem. So how do I do this? How do I make it as if even I have less than 5 characters it will not only type it out but also continue to the next problem? I've kind of figured out that i have to use simple "if sequences" but I have no clue on how I should apply it as all of my attempts have failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL54r.png)

My problem should be able to execute all of these inputs and give the following outputs:

```
Tye a string with max 5 characters: Hi
You typed the string: Hi

Tye a string with max 5 characters: Hello
You typed the string: Hello

Tye a string with max 5 characters: Hey there
You typed the string: Hey t

Tye a string with max 5 characters: 
You typed the string:
```

Comment: It's Ada, not ADA. Please post code, not links to images.

Comment: Use a `declare` block with `I : String := Get_Line;`. I think that should work, I don't do such input.

Comment: I cant get it to work. I was told that I have to use a simple if sequence but I just cant get it to work...

Comment: Please redo you question and show us CODE.

Comment: Alright, just did

Comment: If you type in `H e y` and stop, exactly how is the program supposed to realise that you’ve finished? You have to let it know somehow

Comment: I answered this on Reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/ada/comments/pmd6xw/ada_string_output/hcjqjsm?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Answer (score 1):

The Get_Line function takes two parameters named Item, which is a string and Last which is an instance of Natural.

Get_Line will read the input to the end of the line or the end of the string, whichever comes first. The Last parameter is an OUT parameter returning the index value of the last character read into the string.
Try the following approach:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure help is
   Input    : String (1..80); -- It need not be only 5 characters
   Length   : Natural;
   Num_Good : Natural := 0;
begin
   while Num_Good < 2 loop
      Put ("Enter a string of 5 characters: ");
      Get_Line (Item => Input, Last => Length);
      if Length = 5 then
         Put_Line (Input (1..Length));
         Num_Good := Num_Good + 1;
      else
         Put_Line ("Error: Input does not contain exactly 5 characters.");
      end if;
   end loop;
end help;
```

Following is a version that uses only the features you describe:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure help2 is
   S : String(1..80);
   I : Integer;
   J : Integer := 0;
begin
   loop
      Put("Enter a string containing 5 characters: ");
      Get_Line (S, I);
      if I = 5 then
         J := J + 1;
         Put_Line (S(1..I));
      end;
      if J = 2 then
         exit;
      end if;
   end loop;
end help2;
```

The program will read the string input by the user and output the string if it contains exactly 5 characters. Nothing will be output if the string does not contain exactly 5 characters. The loop exits when the user successfully enters two strings containing exactly 5 characters.

The following version accepts a string of up to 5 characters.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Up_To_five is
   S : String (1..5);
   I : Integer;
begin
   Put ("Enter a string with a max of 5 characters: ");
   Get_Line (S, I);
   Skip_Line;
   Put ("You typed the string: ");
   Put_Line (S(1..I));
   New_Line;
   Put ("Enter a string with a max of 5 characters: ");
   Get_Line (S, I);
   Skip_Line;
   Put ("You typed the string: ");
   Put_Line (S(1..I));
end Up_To_five;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! While this might work, it is not exactly what I'm looking for as some things like Num_Good, Item => Input, Last => Length is completely new to me. This problem should be solved by only using some of the following: String, Character, Integer Get_Line, Get, Put, Put_Line, loop, if-sequences. I've been working with this problem for several hours... I know what the problem is but I can not find a way to solve it.

Comment: Num_Good is simply the name of a variable I created to count the number of times the user entered 5 characters. Item => Input, Last => Length uses Ada named associations. Most programming languages use only a positional association such as "Put_line (Input, Length)". Ada allows both positional association and named association. Named association directly associates the formal parameter name with the actual parameter name.  Natural is a pre-defined subtype of Integer with a minimum value of 0.

Comment: Yes but I'm not supposed to solve this problem using these yet. As I'm in school and still a beginner we have only learned a few things. So we should only solve this problem with the things we have learned

Comment: The specification of the Get_Line procedure is: "procedure Get_Line (Item : String; Last : Natural); " Every instance of Natural is an instance of Integer. The minimum value Get_Line will assign to Last is 0.

Comment: No, not at all but we are only allowed to apply the things we have learned prior to getting this task.

Comment: The source code you shared above will not compile because you never declare the variable I.

Comment: Also by looking at your solution it's not what I'm looking for either. My problem is "Enter a string with a maximum amount of 5 characters". So I basically need to a enter a string that's between 0-5 characters.

Comment: Your code lets you input "Hey brother" and prints "Hey b", and you say 'all good and clear'.  I thought your problem was to stop the program hanging if you enter fewer than 5 characters.

Comment: @SimonWright No, my problem should be able to execute all of these inputs and give the following outputs: 

Tye a string with max 5 characters: Hi
You typed the string: Hi

Tye a string with max 5 characters: Hello
You typed the string: Hello

Tye a string with max 5 characters: Hey there
You typed the string: Hey t

Tye a string with max 5 characters: 
You typed the string:

Comment: @Jim Rogers I looked at your updated alternate solution. I've actually tried exactly this before and it didn't work at all. What will happen is when the user enter his preferred characters and presses the enter key, you will just get a blank row as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

Your program says

```
Put("Type a string with max 5 characters: ");
Get_Line(S(1..5), I);
```

and you type `hi` and press RET (the return key). `Get_Line` returns, having consumed `h i RET`, setting `S (1 .. 2)` to `hi`, which you print out, and `I` to 2.

Now, your program says

```
Skip_Line;
```

which according to [ARM A.10.5(9)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-5.html#p9)

> ... Reads and discards all characters until a line terminator has been read, ...

and so sits there waiting for another RET.

If on the other hand you type 5 or more characters, `Get_Line` finishes before needing to read the RET, so it’s still there in the input buffer.

So you need to decide whether or not to call `Skip_Line`.

Comment: I tried removing Skip_Line but then I ran into another problem. If I type more than 5 characters, the characters that didn't fit in my first string will automatically transfer to my other string.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said that *your program* needs to decide whether or not to call `Skip_Line`